# Get number of orders each hour using Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Here I have a table of customer orders with columns - (order*id, customer*id, pizzaid, order_time) on hourly based date and time such as (2023-01-01 18:00:00). I  would like to count orders made in each hour.

For example :

```
     Date_time        No.Orders                  
2023-01-01 18:00:00     1   
2023-01-01 18:23:00     2
```

So at the end I should see the count of orders - 2 at 18pm.

I have tried this ...,

```
select order_time, count(order_id) over (partition by order_time)  as num_orders
from pizza_runner.customer_orders
```

But here it is not counting together, but showing the data as it is on table by each row.

Can anyone please help me with this

Expecting to be count the number of orders made in that hour.

Comment: No need for ###.

Comment: sorry what do you mean? @jarlh

Comment: Forpas has fixed it now.

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, sample input data, the expected output corresponding to that input data, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Hour](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour) and [Date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) functions to get the Hour and Date from a datetime field. Then group the results by hour / date to get the count of orders made on that date/ hour

```
SELECT DATE(order_time), HOUR(order_time), COUNT(order_id) as num_orders
FROM pizza_runner.customer_orders
GROUP BY HOUR(order_time), DATE(order_time)
```

this will give you

`2023-01-01 | 18 | 2`

If you don't care about grouping by date you can remove the DATE(order_time) section to group all orders by just the hour